# Vagrant 2.0 never SSH's into the box

Tags: ssh, vagrant, timeout

So I'm trying to access the typical hashicorp box via running

```
vagrant init hashicorp/precise64
```

Then of course run

```
vagrant up
```

Then, once the vagrant file was placed, I run

```
vagrant ssh
```

Then it times out, I was wondering if Vagrant has some sort of verbose mode, but this is all I could get from Vagrant itself

```
monta@users-MacBook-Pro:~$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'vmware_fusion' provider...
==> default: Checking if box 'hashicorp/precise64' is up to date...
==> default: Verifying vmnet devices are healthy...
==> default: Preparing network adapters...
WARNING: The VMX file for this box contains a setting that is automatically overwritten by Vagrant
WARNING: when started. Vagrant will stop overwriting this setting in an upcoming release which may
WARNING: prevent proper networking setup. Below is the detected VMX setting:
WARNING:
WARNING:   ethernet0.pcislotnumber = "32"
WARNING:
WARNING: If networking fails to properly configure, it may require this VMX setting. It can be manually
WARNING: applied via the Vagrantfile:
WARNING:
WARNING:   Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
WARNING:     config.vm.provider :vmare_fusion do |vmware|
WARNING:       vmware.vmx["ethernet0.pcislotnumber"] = "32"
WARNING:     end
WARNING:   end
WARNING:
WARNING: For more information: https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/vmware/boxes.html#vmx-whitelisting
==> default: Fixed port collision for 22 => 2222. Now on port 2200.
==> default: Starting the VMware VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 172.16.117.136:22
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
Timed out while waiting for the machine to boot. This means that
Vagrant was unable to communicate with the guest machine within
the configured ("config.vm.boot_timeout" value) time period.

If you look above, you should be able to see the error(s) that
Vagrant had when attempting to connect to the machine. These errors
are usually good hints as to what may be wrong.

If you're using a custom box, make sure that networking is properly
working and you're able to connect to the machine. It is a common
problem that networking isn't setup properly in these boxes.
Verify that authentication configurations are also setup properly,
as well.

If the box appears to be booting properly, you may want to increase
the timeout ("config.vm.boot_timeout") value.
```

This happens every time. I am using the VMWare Fusion provider, which is an additional plugin that cost extra. I've specified that in the Vagrantfile it seems though.

Any ideas, thoughts, suggestions, would be HIGHLY appreciated. Thank you guys.

Comment: hashicorp/precise64 is really one of the oldest box, referenced in lot of tuts about vagrant but not accurate those days, can you try ubuntu/trusty64 as a replacement

Comment: That's not the issue. I get the same error, but thanks for the advice Frederic. I think the problem lays in the Vagrantfile.

Comment: I have the same issue in Vagrant 2.0.0 and 1.9.8, but not in 1.9.6.